# How to handle errors efficiently in React Native mobile app

Tags: react-native, architecture, expo, mobile-application

I work at a small startup where we have a mobile app that has been in production for the last year. This is the first mobile app I have taken into production, and of course, there are things I wish were handled better.

I am about to start working on a new app, and plan to take into account lessons I have learned, to make this app smoother and just better all round.

One thing I am keen to do, is handle errors better as well as other aspects that effect user experience.

I have a general idea, of essentially creating a wrapper around my apps main functionality, that handles errors and other things. As a simplified example:

```js
<PaperProvider theme={theme}>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Router/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ErrorBoundary>
</PaperProvider>
```

I would like to have a helper library that handles API requests, for `POST`, `PUT`, `GET` etc. And say an error is thrown from the server, it is handled gracefully in the app.

Also, we maintain a minimum API version in our server, that checks API calls from the mobile app to determine whether or not the user is running a supported version of the app. And I would also like to implement some functionality that shows a screen telling the user when we are performing maintenance on the app that requires downtime.

I would love to get some feedback and advice on this before I get too deep and have to make some big changes down the line.

Thanks